# Schrodinger equation solution regularity in two dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

Consider the following Schrodinger equation on $\Omega = (0,2)^2 \subset \mathbb R^2$:
$$(*)\qquad (-\Delta + V(x) ) u(x) = \lambda u(x), \quad \left.u\right\vert_{x\in\partial \Omega} = 0 $$
with non-continuous potential,
$$V(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& x \in S \\ -V_0 \gg 1,& x\in \Omega \setminus S \end{cases}, \qquad S= (0,1)^2\subset \Omega.$$
We know for the 1D analog (finite square well with Dirichlet boundary conditions on an interval $I$), the solution is $C^1(I)$. What can be said about the regularity for $(*)$? I tried integrating,
$$-\int_\Omega \Delta u~dx = \int_{\partial \Omega} \nabla u \cdot n~ ds  = \int_\Omega (\lambda - V(x)) u~dx,$$
but couldn't see how to obtain a statement on the regularity of $u$. Any help? I understand there might be a pole in the gradient at the point $x_0 = (1,1)^T$, but what about on $\Omega\setminus \{x_0\}$? I couldn't find any literature on this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume that $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ is a weak solution to $(\ast)$ ($H^1_0(\Omega)$ is an example of a Sobolev space which are usually the appropriate spaces for constructing solutions to PDEs).

I assume that $V_0$ and $\lambda$ are constants. Since $-\Delta u = \lambda u$ in $S$ and $-\Delta u +V_0u=\lambda u$ in $\Omega \setminus \overline S$, it follows from standard elliptic regularity theory that $u$ is analytic in $S \cup (\Omega \setminus \overline S)$. A reference for this is Ch. 6.3 in *Partial Differential Equations* by Lawrence Evans, but pretty much any textbook on regularity theory of elliptic PDE will prove this.

Note that even though $u$ is analytic in $S \cup (\Omega \setminus \overline S)$ this doesn't mean $u$ is analytic in $\Omega$ - since $V$ is discontinuous across $\partial S$ this will translate to lower regularity of $u$ across $\partial S$. However, we can still say something about the regularity of $u$ in $\Omega$.

Indeed, it follows from the Harnack inequality of Evans and Safonov (see see ch. 9 in *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order* by Gilbarg and Trudinger particularly Cor 9.29), we have that $u \in C^\alpha (\overline \Omega)$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Next, re-write $(\ast)$ as: $$ \tag{$\ast\ast$}-\Delta u = f:=\lambda u -Vu, $$ and we know that $f \in L^\infty(\Omega)$. From the Calderon-Zygmund theory of elliptic PDE (see ch. 9 in *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order* by Gilbarg and Trudinger), this implies that $ u \in W^{2,p}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ for all $p> 1$ which, by Sobolev embedding, implies that $ u \in C^{1,\gamma}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ for all $\gamma \in (0,1)$. This is just about as good as you can get since $u$ is definitely not in $C^2(\Omega)$ - if you had that $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ then the left hand side of $(\ast\ast)$ is continuous but the right hand side is discontinuous. The only way you could improve this regularity is by showing $u\in C^{1,1}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ - you could possibly obtain this by applying some of the techniques used to prove regularity of solutions to Free Boundary Problems, for example see *Regularity of Free Boundaries in Obstacle-Type Problems* by Petrosyan, Shahgholian, and Uraltseva.

---

*To summarise:* You can say $u$ is analytic on $S \cup (\Omega \setminus \overline S)$ and is $ u \in C^{1,\gamma}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ for all $\gamma \in (0,1)$. It is also possible that $ u \in C^{1,1}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$, but no better.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very thorough response! This was very helpful.